# Kotlin REPL with Android Classes unStub!ed

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, read-eval-print-loop

I like the Kotlin REPL in Idea / Android-Studio - but as an Android Developer I often run into Stub! problems here. When writing unit-tests I am using [unmock](https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin) to work around this problem. Is there a way to use the same method used there for the Kotlin REPL plugin?

[[image: image showing the problem[2]]

Answer (score 1):

All android (and java.lang.*) classes are placeholders in an Android project. This is because android does not use standard java class files to store the compiled code and there is no way to directly run this code on a computer.

You simply can't use the REPL with android classes, they will only exist on an actual device or emulator.

If you do not care about correctness, then you can use Robolectric's implementation of Android by adding it as a dependency to the project.
To make sure it does not collide with the actual implementation you should probably do this with a separate module dedicated to the REPL.

Robolectic's dependency used by unmock is: `org.robolectric:android-all:7.1.0_r7-robolectric-0`

Comment: Have you looked at unmock? What is the reason the same method cannot be used here - there you also need no emulator/device

Comment: It looks like that plugin uses robolectric's (http://robolectric.org/) implementation of Android. The reason it is not used is because it is unofficial and the behavior is not guaranteed to match a real android device.

Comment: I do not care for guarantees here - and it works really well in unit-tests - just want the same in REPL

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Kotlin REPL in IDEA is provided by the Kotlin IDEA plugin, which has no notion of Android per se, but only looks at what's in the classpath, which in this case is the `android.jar` containing the stubs that throw the exception you mentioned.

Using unmock or even the integrated Android support for removing exceptions from the stubs in tests (see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) at the end of "Mock Android dependencies") won't work as that only affects your Gradle build.

The only solution I can think of is to either open an issue on the [Kotlin tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT) or dig through the [source code of the REPL function in the Kotlin plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/idea/idea-repl) and send a Pull Request.

Comment: Thanks for the info - especially the link to the repl plugin src - just as appendinx - Romain Guy said in chat that layoutlib implementation could be used - not yet sure if I invest the time - https://xkcd.com/1319/